# Performance when dealing with large matrices in React

Tags: reactjs, performance, matrix

I have a Minesweeper game written in React-Redux with somewhat basic visuals.

The game has to support very large boards in the form of matrices (up to 400x400).

In order to avoid mutability, I have to re-render the entire matrix everytime the player presses a tile.

With larger boards (70x70+) it takes a while, and with very large boards its practically unplayable (the initial rendering also times a while).

I've considered React window/React virtuazlied, but typically the whole board (or almost the whole board) fits in the screen so there's nothing to window.
I've also tried using React memo but it doesn't seem to make much of a difference.

Is there anything that will make the game playable with large boards?

This is how to board looks:
[image]

This is how the rendering part looks like:

```
const generateTable = () => {
    return props.gameState.board.map((row, i) => (
      row.map((column, j) => (
        <Tile x={i} y={j} key={`${i},${j}`}
          value={props.gameState.board[i][j]}
          isFlagged={props.gameState.setFlags.has(JSON.stringify([i, j]))}
          isRevealed={props.gameState.revealedTiles.has(JSON.stringify([i, j]))}
          superman={props.superman}
          makePlay={handlePlay}
          setFlag={handleFlag}
          endGame={endGame}
        />
      )
      )
    )
    )
  }

  return (
    <section className='board' style={sectionStyle}>
      {generateTable()}
    </section>
  )
}
```

This is `Tile.js`:

```
const Tile = ({ x, y, value, isFlagged, isRevealed, superman, makePlay, setFlag, endGame }) => {
  const [revealed, setRevealed] = useState(false)
  const [flagged, setFlagged] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    setRevealed(isRevealed)
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [isRevealed])

  useEffect(() => {
    setFlagged(isFlagged)
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [isFlagged])
  const handleLeftClick = (e) => {
    if (flagged && !e.shiftKey) return
    if (e.shiftKey) return setFlag([x, y], value, flagged)
    setRevealed(true)
    if (value === 'M') return endGame(setRevealed)
    makePlay([x, y], value)
  }

  const displayProperValue = () => {
    if (value === 'M') return <Icon fitted={true} size='small' name='fire' />
    if (value === 'E') return ' '
    return value
  }
  if (revealed) {
    return (
      <div className='revealed-tile' style={setStyle()}>
        {displayProperValue()}
      </div>
    )
  } else if (flagged) {
    return (
      <Card className='flagged-tile' raised style={hiddenStyle} onClick={handleLeftClick}>
        <Icon fitted={true} name='font awesome flag' />
      </Card>
    )
  } else if (value === 'M' && superman) {
    return (
      <Card className='superman-tile' raised style={hiddenStyle} onClick={handleLeftClick}>
        <Icon fitted={true} name='exclamation' color='red' />
      </Card>
    )
} else {
  return (
    <Card className='hidden-tile' raised style={{...hiddenStyle, color: 'grey'}} onClick={handleLeftClick}>
      {'?'}
    </Card>
  )
}
}
```

Comment: Please add some code exaple

Comment: did you try immutablejs?

Comment: @Antoni added, let me know if you need other parts

Comment: @AdolfoOnrubia How will it help with performance?

Comment: In my experience working with long lists was helpfull. Are those `has` function applying a hard logic?

Comment: There is no way to help you without seeing the whole code

Comment: @AdolfoOnrubia those are simple `set.has(JSON.stringify([x, y]))` calls, the slowness lies in the rendering rather than the computations

Comment: @vkurchatkin I've added the Tile component code

Comment: Too many ifs implies that will be adding and removing thousand of items to/from DOM, avoid using thos ifs there create another component and pass flasg as props, those component that only receives primitives use `React.memo`
Remove unnecesary code? useEffect(() => {
    setFlagged(isFlagged)
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [isFlagged])

Comment: @AdolfoOnrubia breaking `Tile.js` into four subcomponents wrapped in `memo` actually sounds like a good idea, I'll try and report back!

Answer (score 0):

Use Redux!
You rerender EVERY tile if something in this array changes. Connect every single Tile with the redux store and get your values by an id or index to reduce rerender. At the end only the changed component should render.

```
 <Tile x={i} y={j} key={`${i},${j}`}
          value={props.gameState.board[i][j]}
          isFlagged={props.gameState.setFlags.has(JSON.stringify([i, j]))}
          isRevealed={props.gameState.revealedTiles.has(JSON.stringify([i, j]))} // do this in the component and not pass the value
          superman={props.superman}
          makePlay={handlePlay}
          setFlag={handleFlag}
          endGame={endGame}
        />
```

Instead, only pass

```
 <Tile x={i} y={j} key={`${i},${j}`}
          superman={props.superman}
          makePlay={handlePlay}
          setFlag={handleFlag}
          endGame={endGame}
        />
```

than you should connect your function to the redux store like

```
const Tile = ({ x, y, value, isFlagged, isRevealed, superman, makePlay, setFlag, endGame, gameState }) => {
  const [ currentValue, setValue ] = useState(gameState.board[x][y])
  // some fancy stuff

  useEffect((
    // do something
  ) => {}, [ gameState.board[x][y] ])


  return (<div>{currentValue}<div/>)
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) {
  return {
    gamestate: state.yourStore.gameState,
  }
}

connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Tile)
```